# Reconnect Segmented Data into Original Database

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to run a k-means cluster analysis in R using only a subset of data from my data source. I have created the subset (as dataframe) because I am only interested in using these variables for segmentation, and the rest of the variables will be used to describe the segments.

After the k-means clustering is done, I was wondering how I could connect the clustering results back to my original dataset, which include the descriptive variables as well.

Please let me know if I could provide any clarifications on my questions. Many thanks in advance.

Cheers,
AC

Comment: It would help if you could show, using code and some example data, what you're talking bout. See if the `iris` data set in R is fits your needs.

Comment: Read the manual page for kmeans (if you are using the version that comes with base R and not a version in some other package). The kmeans() function returns a list and the first element of the list (named cluster) is the one that you want to add to your data. It indicates what cluster each row belongs to. None of the other parts of the list are relevant since they do not refer to each row of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You get a cluster label for each point.

These should refer to the same samples as for your original data.